# acrobat DC - launch javascript on startup

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to hide a (form) field when another field contains a certain value.

It works when I use it on "prepare form" but the script is not launch on startup.

```
var test = this.getField("p1_data_ismarie");  
var aEffacer = this.getField("p1_data2_veuf_de");
if(test.value=='X '){
    aEffacer .display = display.hidden;
}
```

I tried it with document's javascript and it look like nothing happens.

I'm using Adobe Acrobat DC 2019.0.21.20056.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the script was launching before data importation, that's the reason it didn't work as expected.

My solution here was : I added an action (acrobat dc form editor) on the first field when that element is selected (my javascript script).

So users just have to click on the first field to activate the script.

(adobe forum helped me so I share it here too) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor typo in your code. See the next to the last line. Remove the space after aEffacer.

```
var test = this.getField("p1_data_ismarie");  
var aEffacer = this.getField("p1_data2_veuf_de");
if(test.value=='X '){
   aEffacer.display = display.hidden;
}
```

Comment: ... but my problem is that I can't launch this script on document startup

Comment: Have you added it to the document level script outside of a function? By default, the UI creates a function when you first open the document script, just delete what's there and paste your script in.

Comment: yes I didn't put it in a function and it's not working